# Content Margin Depend on Other Div by Using Display Table-Cell

Tags: html, css

I have created 2 div next to each other (Left and Right) the height depend on each other I just use display: table-cell for it.
If any item has margin on the left div it affect right div content, content going down while I increase the margin of left div how to solve it ?
Thank you.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="left">
  <p class="prag">
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. 
  </p>
</div>

<div id="right">
<p class="prag2">
  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. 
  </p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.prag{
  margin-top:200px;
}
#left{
  width:200px;
  height:auto;
  display:table-cell;
    background-color: red;

}
#right{
  width:200px;
  height:auto;
  display:table-cell;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I added sorry forgot it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use vertical aling and add to main div display: table;

```
  .prag{
      margin-top:200px;
    }
    #left{
      width:200px;
      height:auto;
      display:table-cell;
        background-color: red;

    }
    #right{
      width:200px;
      height:auto;
      display:table-cell;
      background-color: blue;
      vertical-align: top;

    }
    #container{
    display:table;
    }
```